# How to prevent access to Model by id with JWTAuth and Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, authorization, eloquent

I'm building some API endpoints with Laravel, and I'm using JWTAuth as the token provider for authorizing requests.

I've gotten the setup to protect a group of API routes that works correctly using:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1', 'middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function() {
    Route::resource('messages', 'MessagesController');
});
```

The `Message` model belongs to a `User`

I'm attempting to perform some requests using that relationship while keeping the request from providing data that didn't belong to the user:

1. Get a list of the logged in user's messages
2. Get an individual message of the logged in user

---

The main question I have is how to prevent the user from accessing a `Message` that does not belong to them. I have this in my controller:

```
public function show($message_id)
{
    $message = Message::findOrFail($message_id);
    return $message;
}
```

That obviously will return the `Message` regardless of whether or not it belongs to that user.  **Any suggestions on how to improve that to restrict accessing other user's messages?**

---

For the listing of all messages, I was able to do the following in the controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $user_id = Auth::User()->id;
    $messages = Message::where('user_id', $user_id)->paginate(10);
    return $messages;
}
```

This works, but I'm not sure this is the best way to do it. Maybe it is, but some feedback would be appreciated. I'm confused as to whether or not the middleware should be handling what the user has access to or if it should be part of the eloquent query?

Comment: You probably want a [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#global-scopes). You can apply the scope to all queries on a given model if wanted

Comment: Found any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is,

> how to prevent the user from accessing a Message that does not belong
>   to them.

Thats falls under [Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization)

You can use `Gates` to Authorize users and I think it's the best approach here. Fist of all you'd need a `Policy` object.

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Message;

class MessagePolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine if the given Message can be viewed by the user.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Message  $Message
     * @return bool
     */
    public function view(User $user, Message $Message)
    {
        return $user->id === $Message->user_id;
        // Here this User's id should match with the user_id of the Massage
    }
}
```

You can even generate the boilerplate like this,

```
php artisan make:policy MessagePolicy --model=Message
```

Then you can register it in your `AuthServiceProvider` like this,

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Message;
use App\Policies\MessagePolicy;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        Message::class => MessagePolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::define('view-message', 'MessagePolicy@view');
    }
}
```

And in your Controller you can use it like this,

```
public function show($message_id)
{
    if (Gate::allows('view-message', Message::findOrFail($message_id)) {
        return $message;
    }
}
```

Note: Please use this code snippet as a reference or a starting point since I haven't tested it properly. But underlying concept is correct. Use this as pseudocode. If something wrong found, please update it here :)